# websocket onmessage not firing during ajax request

Tags: javascript, perl, mojolicious

I have a web application that performs a Jquery .post request for database queries.  I also have three different web socket connections that are used to push status updates from the server to the client (CPU and Memory stats in a live chart, database status, and query queue).  While a query is not running, everything works smoothly, but once a query is started (post request), then the three web socket connections seem to hang/block while waiting for the query to return.  I was reading about this and have not found any relevant answers...I suspect that it is probably something really dumb on my part...but this has had me scratching my head for the better part of a day now.  I thought I might try moving the web socket connections to web workers...but in theory, the POST should not be blocking to begin with...So, here are the relevant snippets of code...The full source is a couple of thousand lines of code...so I didn't want to inundate anyone with it...but could show it if it is useful.  So, the big question is what am I doing wrong here?  Or perhaps, am I misunderstanding how AJAX calls work as far as blocking goes?

```
    // query execution button that grabs the query for the most recently focused query source (SPARQL editor, history, or canned)
      $("#querySubmitButton").on("click", function(e) {
        // Disable the query button
        $("#querySubmitButton").attr('disabled',true);

        // Let's make sure we are clearing out the work area and the popup contents
        $("#viz").empty();

        // Get YASQE to tell us what type of query we are running
        var queryType = editor.getQueryType();

        // refactored so that we can clean up the on-click function and also make other query types in a more modular way
        switch(queryType) {
          case 'SELECT':
            sparqlSelect();
            break;
          case 'CONSTRUCT':
            sparqlConstruct();
            break;
          case 'ASK':
            sparqlAsk();
            break;
          case 'DESCRIBE':
            sparqlDescribe();
            break;
          case 'INSERT':
            sparqlInsert();
            break;
          default:
            popup.show("Unrecognized query type.","error");
            break;
        }
      });

// Functions to do each of the query types (SELECT, CONSTRUCT, ASK, DESCRIBE, INSERT)
  // SELECT
  function sparqlSelect() {
    $.post("sparqlSelect", { database: $("#DB_label").html(),'query': editor.getValue() }).done(function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
      // Enable the query button
      $("#querySubmitButton").removeAttr('disabled');

      // If the query worked, store it
      storeQueryHistory(query);

      // if the previous query was a CONSTRUCT, then lets hide the graph metrics button
      $("#nav-trigger-graphStatistics").fadeOut(800);

      // Need to slide the query menu back
      sliders("in",$("#nav-trigger-query").attr("id"));

      var columns = [];
      var fields = [];
      var comboboxFields = [];


      // Hide the graph search panel
      $("#graphSearch").fadeOut(1400);

      // Show the results and visualization button/tab
      $("#nav-trigger-results").fadeIn(1400);
      $("#nav-trigger-visualization").fadeIn(1400);


      $.each(data.results.head.vars, function(index, value) {
        columns.push({'field': value, 'title': value});
        var to = {};
        to[value] = {type: "string"};
        fields.push(to);

        // Let's also populate the two Comboboxes for the Visualization while we are at it
        comboboxFields.push({'text': value, 'value': value});
      });

      // Now, set the two combobox datasources for visualizations
      var categoriesDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
          data: comboboxFields
      });
      vizCategoryAxis.setDataSource(categoriesDS);

      var valuesDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
          data: comboboxFields
      });
      vizValueAxis.setDataSource(valuesDS);

      var dataBindings = [];
      $.each(data.results.results.bindings, function(index1, value) {
        var tempobj = {};
        $.each(value, function(k1,v1) {
          tempobj[k1] = v1.value;
        });
        tempobj.id=index1;
        dataBindings.push(tempobj);
      });

      var configuration = {
        dataSource: {
          data: dataBindings,
          pageSize: 25
        },
        height: 400,
        scrollable: true,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: true,
        reorderable: true,
        resizable: true,
        toolbar: ["excel"],
        excel: {
          allPages: true,
          filterable: true,
          proxyURL: "/saveExcel"
        },
        pageable: {
          input: true,
          numeric: false,
          pageSizes: true
        },
        'columns': columns,
        dataBound: function(e) {
          $(e.sender.element).find('td').each(function() {
            var temp = $(this).html();
            if (isUrl(temp)) {
              $(this).html('<a href="' + temp + '" target="_blank">' + temp + '</a>');
            }
          });
        }
      };

      // Create the popup window
      var gridWindow = $("#resultsPopup").kendoWindow({
        width: "70%",
        title: "Query Results",
        actions: [
            "Minimize",
            "Maximize",
            "Close"
        ]
      }).data('kendoWindow');

      // Center and show the popup window
      gridWindow.center().open();

      // Create/update/refresh the grid
      resultsGrid.setOptions(configuration);
      resultsGrid.dataSource.page(1);

      $("#nav-trigger-results").on('click',function() {
        // Center and show the popup window
        gridWindow.center().open();
      });
    }).fail(function(xhr) {
      // If we are timed-out
      if (xhr.status === 401) {
        // First, clear the host, database, and status text
        $("#host_label").html('');
        $("#DB_label").html('');
        $("#status_label").html('');

        // Next, disable the query button
        $("#querySubmitButton").attr('disabled',true);

        // Change "login" tab text color to red so we know we are no longer logged in
        var styles = { 'color': "#FFCCD2" };
        $("#nav-trigger-login").css(styles);

        popup.show("Session for " + host + " has timed out, please log back in.","error");
      }
      else {
        // Enable the query button
        $("#querySubmitButton").removeAttr('disabled');
        popup.show("Error, no results (" + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + ")","error");
      }
    });
  }

  // Function to connect to the query queue websocket
  function queueWebsocketConnect() {
    var qws = new WebSocket('wss://endeavour:3000/queue');

    // Let's disconnect our Websocket connections when we leave the app
    $(window).on('unload', function() {
      console.log('Websocket connection closed');
      qws.close();
    });

    // Status websocket onopen
    qws.onopen = function () {
      console.log('Websocket connection opened');
      popup.show("Websocket connection opened","success");
    };

    qws.onclose = function (event) {
      console.log('Websocket connection closed');
      popup.show("Websocket connection closed","info");
    };

    qws.onmessage = function (msg) {
      var res = JSON.parse(msg.data);
      var tableRows = '<thead><tr><td>Query Position</td><td>Query ID</td><td>Kill/Cancel Query</td></tr></thead><tbody>';
      if (res.executing != null && res.entry.length > 0) {
        $("#queryQueue").empty();
        tableRows += '<tr><td>1</td><td>' + res.executing.id + '</td><td><input type="button" class="k-button" value="Kill"></td></tr>';

        $.each(res.entry, function(index,object) {
          tableRows += '<tr><td>' + (object.pos + 1) + '</td><td>' + object.query.id + '</td><td><input type="button" class="k-button" value="Cancel"></td></tr>';
        });
        tableRows += '</tbody>';
        $("#queryQueue").html(tableRows);
      }
      else if (res.executing != null) {
        $("#queryQueue").empty();
        tableRows += '<tr><td>1</td><td>' + res.executing.id + '</td><td><input type="button" class="k-button" value="Kill"></td></tr>';
        tableRows += '</tbody>';
        $("#queryQueue").html(tableRows);
      }
      else {
        console.log(res);
        $("#queryQueue").empty();
      }
    };
  }

  // Function to connect to the stats websocket
  function websocketConnect () {
    // Set up websocket connection for system stats
    var ws = new WebSocket('wss://endeavour:3000/stats');

    // Let's disconnect our Websocket connections when we leave the app
    $(window).on('unload', function() {
      console.log('Websocket connection closed');
      ws.close();
    });

    // Status websocket onopen
    ws.onopen = function () {
      console.log('Websocket connection opened');
      popup.show("Websocket connection opened","success");
    };

    // Status websocket onclose
    ws.onclose = function (event) {
      // Disable the query button
        $("#querySubmitButton").attr('disabled',true);

      // Change "login" tab text color to red so we know we are no longer logged in
      var styles = { 'color': "#FFCCD2" };
      $("#nav-trigger-login").css(styles);

      // Clear the host, database, and status text
      $("#host_label").html('');
      $("#DB_label").html('');
      $("#status_label").html('');
      console.log('Websocket connection closed');
      popup.show("Websocket connection closed","error");

      $("#websocketReconnectButtonYes").on('click', function() {
        websocketConnect();
        queueWebsocketConnect();
        websocketReconnect.close();
      });

      $("#websocketReconnectButtonNo").on('click', function() {
        websocketReconnect.close();
      });

      websocketReconnect.center().open();
    };

    // When updates are received, push them out to update the details
    var logoutCount = 0;
    ws.onmessage = function (msg) {
      if (msg.data === 'loggedOut') {
        // Ensure we only emit this one time instead of a stream of them
        if (logoutCount == 0) {
          // Disable the query button
          $("#querySubmitButton").attr('disabled',true);

          // Change "login" tab text color to red so we know we are no longer logged in
          var styles = { 'color': "#FFCCD2" };
          $("#nav-trigger-login").css(styles);

          // Clear the host, database, and status text
          $("#host_label").html('');
          $("#DB_label").html('');
          $("#status_label").html('');

          console.log("Session for " + $("#host_label").html() + " has timed out, please log back in.");
          popup.show("Session for " + $("#host_label").html() + " has timed out, please log back in.","error");
        }
        logoutCount = 1;
      }
      else {
        logoutCount = 0;
        var res = JSON.parse(msg.data);
        var host = $("#host_label").html();
        var pdatabase = $("#DB_label").html();
        var pstatus = $("#status_label").html();

        // Disable the query button unless the database is "CONNECTED"
        if ($("#status_label").html() !== res.current.databaseStatus) {
          if (res.current.databaseStatus !== "CONNECTED") {
            $("#querySubmitButton").attr('disabled',true);
          }
          else {
            $("#querySubmitButton").removeAttr('disabled');
          }

          if (res.current.databaseStatus == 'CONNECTED' || res.current.databaseStatus == 'STOPPED') {
            $("#startDB").removeAttr('disabled');
          }
          else {
            $("#startDB").attr('disabled',true);
          }
        }

        // Maybe a more intelligent way to do this, but need to make sure that if the cookie is still valid, then populate the database login stuff
        if ($("#dbConfigHost").val() == "" && $("#dbConfigUser").val() == "") {
          $("#dbConfigHost").val(res.host);
          $("#dbConfigUser").val(res.user);

          // Change "login" tab text color to green so we know we are logged in
          var styles = { 'color': "#C5E6CC" };
          $("#nav-trigger-login").css(styles);

          var databasesDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: res.databases.database
          });
          databasePicker.setDataSource(databasesDS);
        }

        // Update the labels when values change
        if (res.host != $("#host_label").html()) {
          $("#host_label").html(res.host);
          popup.show("Host changed to " + res.host,"info");
        }
        if (pdatabase != res.current.name) {
          $("#DB_label").html(res.current.name);
          popup.show("Database changed to " + res.current.name ,"info");
        }
        if (pstatus != res.current.databaseStatus) {
          $("#status_label").html(res.current.databaseStatus);
        }

        // Update the sparklines
        cpulog.options.series[0].data = res.system.cpu;
        cpulog.refresh();
        memlog.options.series[0].data = res.system.mem;
        memlog.refresh();
      }
    };

    // Open the websocket connection to listen for changes to the query list
    var queryWS = new WebSocket('wss://endeavour:3000/queryList');

    queryWS.onmessage = function(msg) {
      var res = JSON.parse(msg.data);
      var queriesDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
          data: res
      });
      cannedQuery.setDataSource(queriesDS);
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I guess when one has been heading down one road for a while, one assumes that it is in the right direction.  After further head-scratching, I found the issue and it was related to the blocking/non-blocking nature of my backend web-framework.  As it turns out, in Mojolicious (Perl web-framework), http calls can be either synchronous or asynchronous depending on how one writes the call.

```
my $tx = $ua->get('http://foo.bar?query=getSomeFoo');
if($tx->success) {
    $self->render($tx->res->content);
}
else {
    $self->rendered($tx->res->code);
}
```

This is a blocking/synchronous request.  Nothing happens until after the GET finishes.  On the other hand, if one writes the request like so, it is an asynchronous request:

```
$ua->get('http://foo.bar?query=getSomeFoo' => sub {
    my ($ua,$tx) = @_;
    if($tx->success) {
        $self->render($tx->res->content);
    }
    else {
        $self->rendered($tx->res->code);
    }
});
```

So, if anyone else has encountered this issue...here is the answer.  If I am the only idiot on the planet that has committed this blunder...then I guess I have put my shame out there for all to have a good chuckle at.

Bottom line was that this was well documented in the Mojolicious docs...but I had been doing it one way for so long that I completely forgot about it.

Cheers!